# Method [show] does not exist in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass multiple parameter from href and want to get with Input::get() in my function. I get this error :

> bad method call exception Method [show] does not exist error.

My route is: `Route::get('workorder/test', 'WorkOrderController@test');` and passing on this way

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit" href="{{URL::to('workorder/test?work_order_id='.$item->id.'&site_office_id='.$item->site_office_id)}}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-edit text-white"></i>
                                            </a>
```

I want to get from my function:

```
public function test() {
    echo Input::get('work_order_id');exit;
}
```

These are my routes for the given controller:

```
Route::resource('workorder', 'WorkOrderController'); 
Route::get('workorder/filter', 'WorkOrderController@filter'); 
Route::post('workorder/proceedworkorder', 'WorkOrderController@proceedworkorder'); 
Route::get('workorder/addworkorder', 'WorkOrderController@addworkorder'); 
Route::get('workorder/approve/{id?}', 'WorkOrderController@approve'); 
Route::get('workorder/decline/{id?}', 'WorkOrderController@decline'); 
Route::get('workorder/test', 'WorkOrderController@test');
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: The error is not associated with your code. It's caused by another route or cached route missing the `show` method. Check your routes again and run `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: can you put you routes please ?

Comment: this is my route Route::get('workorder/test', 'WorkOrderController@test');

Comment: this is my all route for this controller :                     Route::resource('workorder', 'WorkOrderController');
    Route::get('workorder/filter', 'WorkOrderController@filter');
    Route::post('workorder/proceedworkorder', 'WorkOrderController@proceedworkorder');
    Route::get('workorder/addworkorder', 'WorkOrderController@addworkorder');
    Route::get('workorder/approve/{id?}', 'WorkOrderController@approve');
    Route::get('workorder/decline/{id?}', 'WorkOrderController@decline');
    Route::get('workorder/test', 'WorkOrderController@test');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing:

```
Route::resource('workorder', 'WorkOrderController');
```

This method alone [maps out all the normal RESTful endpoints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). And is potentially overriding the test endpoint.

> This single route declaration creates multiple routes to handle a
>   variety of RESTful actions on the photo resource. Likewise, the
>   generated controller will already have methods stubbed for each of
>   these actions, including notes informing you which URIs and verbs they
>   handle.

If you need to keep it I would put in:

```
Route::resource('workorder', 'WorkOrderController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```